# MongoDB with Python - Remove a specific element from the document

Tags: python, mongodb

I have the follwing documnet in the MongoDB -

```
    _id : ObjectId("5e2f304068e7f832db1a7f55")
    ListOfNames : Array
          0: "John"
          1: "Chris"
          2: "Bob"
          3: "David"
          4: "Carol"
```

How can I remove the element - "John" from the documnet with help of Python.

Expected output -

```
    _id : ObjectId("5e2f304068e7f832db1a7f55")
    ListOfNames : Array
          0: "Chris"
          1: "Bob"
          2: "David"
          3: "Carol"
```

Tried using pull, but no luck.

Comment: This is a common use case of the $pull operator. Please describe the solution that you have tried already.

Comment: Developed below code - 


/In a mongo_db config file 
LIST_OF_NAMES = MONGO_DB['ListOfNames']

/In the main py file
LIST_OF_NAMES.update_one(
 {'$pull':
  {LIST_OF_NAMES:
   {'$in':
    ["John"]
   }
  }
 }
)

Answer (score 0):

General syntax for updating a document in mongodb:

```
db.collection.updateOne(<filter>, <update>);
```

`filter` and `update` for removing the element "John" from the field "ListOfNames" from a document having _id 5e2f304068e7f832db1a7f55

```
db.collection.updateOne(
  { "_id": ObjectId("5e2f304068e7f832db1a7f55") },
  { "$pull": { "ListOfNames": "John" } }
);
```

The db and collection names are not provided in the question, assuming the collection name to be `test`, the `pymongo` call to perform the same operation would be:

```
db.test.update_one(
  {'_id': ObjectId('5e2f304068e7f832db1a7f55')},
  {'$pull': {'ListOfNames': 'John'}}
)
```